# Need help fixing 'not defined' error (and other things)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on a school assignment and we need to:

Write a program that multiplies two integers together then displays their product that many times. For example, 3 * 3 would display 9, 9 times.

I don't know much about code and am really struggling. :(
(Edit: Using Python 2)

Having `num1 = input("...")`
instead of `num1 = int(input("..."))`
and 
`if numInput() == int:`
instead of 
`if numInput() == integer:`

Gives:

> NameError: name 'num1' is not defined

However, if i leave in 
`if numInput() == integer:`
and 
`num1 = int(input("..."))`
it gives

> NameError: name 'integer' is not defined

```
while True:
    def numInput():

        num1 = input("Please input your first integer: ")
        num2 = input("Please input your second integer: ")

    if numInput() == integer:
        continue
    else:
        print("You must enter a number (i.e. 0,1,2...)")
    num3 = (num1 * num2)
    print("The product of those numbers is: ")
    print((str(num3) + ' ') * num3)
    if input('Do you want to go again? (y/n) ') == 'n':
        break
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  They behave differently when entering a number into `input`.

Comment: Sorry, should've defined that, we're using python 2

Comment: Ok, in Python 2 `input` tries to figure out what you enter.  If it looks like an integer, it converts it to an integer.  So you just need to test if it's an integer.  If you just want to check for an ordinary integer, you can do `isinstance(num1, int)` and similarly for `num2`.  If you want to accept long as well (in Python 2 they are distinct types), you can use `isinstance(num1, (int, long))`.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks so much :)

Comment: Hi Morenz - welcome to Stack Overflow! If you find something to add to your post after having written it (such as the version of Python as shown in the comments), editing your question and adding anything helpful can aid other Stack Overflow users in quickly identifying issues and talking points. For extra brownie points, put your you can add your edits under a bold/heading **Edit** at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `if numInput() == integer:`

You haven't defined what the integer variable is. I'm assuming you want to test if the `numInput` is an integer. However, you will need to test both `num1` and `num2` To do this you can use either the `type` or `isinstance` method.

The following revisions could work:

`if type(num1) == int and type(num2) == int`

or `if isinstance(num1, int) and isinstance(num2, int)`

As a note, this won't work if you want to support longs or floats but that can be added pretty easily.